# ELK warning courier fetch shards failed

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using ELK for log aggregation. When I refresh the Dashboard, sometimes I got the warning:

```
Courier Fetch: 46 of 345 shards failed
```

I do not know how to resolve this issue? Does anyone got the same warning?

[image]